I cannot access some ports on my Contabo provider VPS Server
My Contabo VPS with Debian 12 and no iptables rules enabled, gives me no access to some ports. For instances, ports 80 and 443 are allowed, but 8080 and some others are not.
Is there a kind of default segurity groups enabled in Contabo VPS? I don't see it.
I used nc to test sending and receiving data to those ports (8080, etc.), but with no result. However, I can receive data if I use ports 80, 25, and 443.

Well, I thought I had the same problem with Cantabo after setting up a new server. Turned out it had nothing to do with Cantbo, but with the firewall of our company that only allowed certain ports like 80 and 443, but not 8080 for example. When I tested the connection from my mobile phone it just worked...

Perfect! Our firewall was blocking those ports in the output. Thanks You very much!
